# Is it possible to keep static table reference in iis somehow so that each instance does not need to load?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, caching

I am creating a C# dll, which will be called by RIA services, which in turn will perform some computation. Every time, the computation is called, I need to load a reference table. I am trying to see if it possible cache this table somehow and then use it from there instead of loading from data base every time since this table seldom changes(may be once in a year). Is it possible?
Thanks,

Comment: Have you considered... Cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the  [System.Web.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) class to keep a single instance of the table for your app domain.